# Split up the field and form new map in Apex

Tags: apex, list

I am having one unique scenario, as if ResV is coming as below in the list

```
List<AsQres> assresponseMulti = new List<AsQres>();
```

output as below -

(ASQREsponse":{
Id=0jb2z000000Cauijui,
AssID=0U32z000000Cui9io,
"ResV=Bihar;Jhseed",
"Nams=test_Ques",
AsQID=0lF2z00000klo09
}

If ResV is coming like "ResV=Bihar;Jhseed",  in the above list i need to store the value in new list as below

```
(ASQREsponse":{
      "ResV=Bihar",
       "Nams=test_Ques",
       
    },
ASQREsponse":{
      "ResV=Jhseed",
       "Nams=test_Ques",
       
    },
```

Kindly help me to separate the above ResV as new element in the list.

Tried below approach

```
if(ASQREsponse !=  null) {
   for(ASEObj ase :  ASQREsponse) {
        if(ase.ResV.contains(;)){
        //put new key value pair as above
        
            }
            }
        }
```

Comment: We need more context. How did you arrive at this particular string?

Comment: Apology @sfdcfox , i am getting the list from the database in salesforce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `AsQres` class has both a `Name` and a `ResV` property, you don't need the `contains()`, you could just leverage [`split()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_split) behavior: if there are no `;` it returns a list with one element, the whole string.
I.E. if `ase.ResV` holds `qwerty`, calling `ase.ResV.split(';')` returns a list with a single string: `qwerty`

So you could loop over that list and create a new `AsQres` setting its name equals to the one of the `ASEObj` object coming from the outer for-loop and setting `ResV` equals to the current string coming from the split.

```java
if (ASQREsponse != null) {
    for (ASEObj ase :  ASQREsponse) {
        for (String resv : ase.ResV.split(';')) {
            AsQres asq = new AsQres();
            asq.Name = ase.Name;
            asq.ResV = resv;
            assresponseMulti.add(asq);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou @RubenDG